# How to prevent a logged in user from visiting the login page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an application in MVC3 where I have a login page. Once a user logs into the page, the problem comes when he/she clicks on the back button of the browser, it takes them back to the Login page which I don't want.

Cutting the long story short, I want a login functionality working exactly the same as facebook, gmail  and other websites like them has.

One way I thought of working on is to find a way to control the browser back button after logging-in and accordingly if it is clicked, redirect the user to the same logged-in page. 
I have done a lot of research but nothing seemed to work for me.

Any would would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Although the solution provided by Darin will work. But if you ask me, facebook has not implemented that solution.
I believe a proper solution should not be very difficult to implement.
 We need to do two things.

**Make sure log in page is not accessible to authenticated users.**

you can modify the login get method as follows

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //Important
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller"); // ur action and controller
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Make sure that login page is not cached**

put this code in the above method to make sure that logic page is never returned from cache

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

alternatively you can use `NoCache` ActionFilter on Login method. It will do the same thing as above.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the following script in your login view (the one that contains the username and password fields):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
</script>
```

Comment: Is this how Google/Facebook doing it? I like how Facebook knows that I am already logged in and automatically show my Home.

Answer (score 0):

If your login httpget action had a NoCache action filter to prevent the browser caching it, then if the user went back to it via the back button, the browser would request a new login page and the controller action code could detect that the user was already authenticated and redirect them to a different page.